# How to define removable devices as music player & e-book reader?

Tags: automount, system-settings, mtp, ebooks

I would like to use the removable media settings to open Rhythmbox when I insert my music player, and Calibre when I insert an E-book reader. The player is a Sansa Clip+ in MTP mode. The reader is a Nook Simple Touch.

Ubuntu 16.04 recognises and mounts both without error. However, it does not recognise the devices as a music player and an e-book reader and then auto-launch either of the programs. Ubuntu instead uses nautilus to open and display both as file systems.

How can I tell Ubuntu that the first device is a music player and the second is an e-book reader, and then command Ubuntu to act accordingly?

I've used Cuttlefish in the past for this process, but unfortunately it isn't available for Xenial. Though in the long-run it's probably best not to rely upon a 3rd party and instead to find a way to make the stock software work as it should.

Thank you for your help.

Eva